# Overwrite field type in inheritance for GSON serialization

Tags: java, json, serialization, deserialization, gson

I would like to realize the following, having this classes:

```
public class A {
   Data data;
}

public class A extends B {
   boolean data;
}
```

When deserialized I would like to get the following statements to work.

```
new Gson().fromJson("{\"data\": "false\"}", B.class)
new Gson().fromJson("{\"data\": {}}", A.class)
```

Currently, of course it does not work, getting a

`IllegalArgumentException: declares multiple JSON fields named data`

How can I implement it, that the same-named super class field is ignored? I reckon I need to provide a `shouldSkipField` implementation, but I cannot figure out the logic currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that name of fields should not be changed and A class should not know about its children. And I think Gson still doesn't support setter injection. so I don't see any way to do this with Gson. Because as I know you can not override fields in java. But Jackson does support setter injection and with Jackson you could do it very easely. Just override getter and setter and mark them as ignored. Code to test:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    B b = mapper.readValue("{\"data\": \"false\"}", B.class);
    A a = mapper.readValue("{\"data\": {\"id\":5}}", A.class);
    System.out.println(b);
    System.out.println(a);
}

public static class A{
    private Data data;

    public Data getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(Data data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "A{" +
                "data=" + data +
                '}';
    }
}

public static class B extends A{
    private boolean data;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Override
    public Data getData() {
        return super.getData();
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    @Override
    public void setData(Data data) {
        super.setData(data);
    }

    public boolean isData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(boolean data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "B{" +
                "data=" + data +
                '}';
    }
}

public static class Data{
    private int id;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Data{" +
                "id=" + id +
                '}';
    }
}
```

out is:

```
B{data=false}
A{data=Data{id=5}}
```

If Gson also supports setter injection something like this would be possible and with Gson.